# Ubuntu screen as "webcam"

Tags: ubuntu, webcam, screen-capture, video-streaming

I want to enable my screen as a video capture drive, so I can share (stream) my desktop screen instead my webcam.

I'm using Mint 12 (based on Ubuntu).

Answer (score 2):

There are several software that help you doing that. For example:

1. http://www.ws4gl.org/ Webcam Studio for stream your video from different sources, also from desktop.
2. http://recordmydesktop.sourceforge.net/about.php
3. https://launchpad.net/kazam It seems pretty good.
4. http://xvidcap.sourceforge.net/ I used that when i needed to make a video of my desktop

And for another list of available software check that post: 
http://ostatic.com/blog/six-top-screen-capture-tools-for-linux#intro

Hope that this help.

Comment: I don't want to "record my desktop", I want to get my screen and stream it as video input, like a webcam or other device on /dev/video

Comment: Take a look at kazam (it is used to make screencast, and maybe you can stream it in some way, for example using a video streaming software that read from the video that you are recording). And try that software: http://www.ws4gl.org/ It is used to stream from different sources it says also from desktop.

Answer (score 1):

VLC should, in theory be able to take a video stream from your desktop- with "screen://" as your input option and output it to another streaming source. However whether if will work with the software you have in mind would depend on what that software is.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
ffmpeg -f x11grab -framerate 30 -video_size 1920x1080 -i :0.0+1920,0 -f v4l2 -vf scale=3840:-1 -vcodec rawvideo -pix_fmt rgb24 /dev/video1
```

Just do `sudo apt install ffmpeg` first, then you'll probabbly have to create `/dev/video1`, so `touch /dev/video1 && sudo chmod 666 /dev/video*`

Comment: Hey Chicken Soup, thanks for your solution. I think it will work, but I am having issues with ioctl. Any idea how to solve this? [video4linux2,v4l2 @ 0x563e5f1d4ec0] ioctl(VIDIOC_G_FMT): Inappropriate ioctl for device
Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters ?): Inappropriate ioctl for device
Error initializing output stream 0:0 -- 
Conversion failed!

Comment: @mate.gwozdz Does https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/528400/how-can-i-stream-my-desktop-screen-to-dev-video1-as-a-fake-webcam-on-linux answer your question?

Comment: soup Thank you for your help, I've just tried the answer, and keep having the same error. "Inappropriate ioctl for device. Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters ?): Inappropriate ioctl for device". Maybe something to do with virtual box machine

Comment: That's a php error. Double check you're using the latest version of FFmpeg